# How to get lat and lng from google maps Api v2?

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

*I asked this question today and I ask again because I was not clear enough*
I made ​​a class that returns the following values​​:
**lat/lng/current place** **(street, city)**
now,in the **Activity** I need to get the values of the current location and show it on a simple Toast massage.
But when I'm goes outside home I do not get the correct values ​​for my location.
It is remember my last position and not really accurate. And another thing.. the app is published to  the market and there are some crashes from some devices. I do not understand the problem.
I've included the classes code below.

class 1 :

```
public class MapCurrentPlace implements OnMyLocationChangeListener {

public Context context;
double latitude = 0;
double longitude = 0;
String placeName = "";



public MapCurrentPlace(Context context) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
}


public double getLatitude() throws IOException {
    try {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return latitude;
}

public double getLongitude() throws IOException {
    try {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();    
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return longitude;
}


public String getPlaceName() throws IOException {
    try {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();

        //Get location info
        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(context);
        if(location != null && gc !=null){
            List<Address> list = gc.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
            if(list.size()>0){
                String city = list.get(0).getLocality();
                String street = list.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                placeName = city+", "+street+"";        
            }


        }else{
            placeName = "";
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        placeName = "";
    }



    return placeName;
}


@Override
public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        // After this you can call the function to be sure that the application already has a locaiton
    }
}
```

}

class 2 (Activity):

```
    private MapCurrentPlace place;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


try {
        place = new MapCurrentPlace(this);
        double lat = place.getLatitude();
        double lng = place.getLongitude();
        String placeLocation = place.getPlaceName();
        Toast.makeText(this, lat+" "+lng+" "+placeLocation, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}

    }
}
```

*now on my device it work fine but when i go outside it not given me the right location*

here is my users craches&ANRs error1:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.bibas.workclock.tools.MapCurrentPlace.getLatitude(MapCurrentPlace.java:42)
at com.bibas.workclock.MainActivity.startTimer(MainActivity.java:269)
at com.bibas.workclock.MainActivity.onLongClick(MainActivity.java:786)
at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:4376)
at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:17613)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5171)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:564)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

error2:

```
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
at com.bibas.workclock.tools.MapCurrentPlace.getPlaceName(MapCurrentPlace.java:74)
at com.bibas.workclock.MainActivity.startTimer(MainActivity.java:271)
at com.bibas.workclock.MainActivity.onLongClick(MainActivity.java:786)
at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:4511)
at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:18758)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**hope you'll be able to decipher my problem thank you :(((**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You are using *Google Maps V2* which not using the *[locationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)* any more , your class should implements  **[LocationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html)** then ovveride *onLocationChanged* callback which is fired when the device detect new location newer than the current saved one.

  ```
  public class MapCurrentPlace implements OnMyLocationChangeListener{

  public Context context;
  double latitude = 0;
  double longitude = 0;
  String placeName = "";


  public MapCurrentPlace(Context context) {
      super();
      this.context = context;
  }

  public String getPlaceName(Location location) throws IOException {
      try {
          latitude = location.getLatitude();
          longitude = location.getLongitude();

          //Get location info
          Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(context);
          if(location != null && gc !=null){
              List<Address> list = gc.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
              if(list.size()>0){
                  String city = list.get(0).getLocality();
                  String street = list.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                  placeName = city+", "+street+"";        
              }
          }else{
              placeName = "";
          }

      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          placeName = "";
      }
          //Return the place name format "city, street".
      return placeName;
  }

  @Override
  public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
  if(location != null){
         // After this you can call the function to be sure that the application already has a locaiton
   String placeName = getPlaceName(location); //  this is where you should call the method
     }
  }
  ```
- About the first crash, it should be fixed after applying the previous solution , because the problem is when the application get the last known location, sometimes there is no saved location, so the parameter is null and is catches a **NPE**.
- About the second crash, After you return the places, you wrote 'String street = list.get(0).getAddressLine(0);' in *getPlaceName()* method, you didn't check if AddressLine contains items or not, so you get the first item of an empty list

Comment: tnx very much. you can give me please some code example?  or show me some example after i implements what to do?

Comment: So i just needed to add the :"implements OnMyLocationChangeListener" and "@Override
public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
if(location != null){
       latitude = location.getLatitude();
         longitude = location.getLongitude();
       // After this you can call the function to be sure that the application already has a locaiton
   }" !??! and it all work fine?!?!

Comment: Yes this will wait till the application detect a location then call the function, otherwise the function will not be called , you can set a timer to check if the latitude and longitude are not null , it still null after a period of time ( set it as you want and it would be better if more than 15 sec , while showing a progress dialog saying "Waiting for a location" ) if the latitude and longitude are still null then the application couldn't fetch new location

Comment: Wow thank you! but what about : " locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60000, 0,  this);" i dont need it for refreshing?

Comment: No this is not used any more in V2

Comment: I edited my code on the question take a look if its cover all the ather problem

Comment: I updated the getPlaceName method arguments , and onMyLocation call back

Comment: I went outside to check the app and i notice only when i close the app and open again the place name change

Comment: try to leave it open and move outside for 30 sec this should be solve your problem , and you can make a toast in OnMyLocationChanged to check if the function is called.

Comment: ok i go outside now to check it . but what about the lat and lng? Where exactly is changing? we didnt call they on OnMyLocationChanged. and on activity when i call getPlaceName()? i need to insert null to the Brackets?

Comment: I'm back .. and It seems like the OnMyLocationChanged not called at all i make a Toast at this method